# Differential equation leading behavior

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Show that the solution of $x^{3}y''=y$ whose leading behavior as $x\rightarrow0$ is $e^{-2x^{-1/2}}$ is actually given by $x^{3/4}e^{-2x^{-1/2}}$. Do this by writing $y=e^{S(x)}$ and finding the subleading part of S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [WKP approximation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation). See the example which your problem is a special case of it.